# Notification continuously ringing ring. How to make it to ring only once?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-push-notification

i Have used it with notification builder

```
  final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NotificationChannelCreator.COMPLAIN)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.prescient_logo)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    showNotification(notificationBuilder);


}

private void showNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    android.app.Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
    notification.defaults |=  Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
    notification.flags = android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | android.app.Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;   
    notificationManager.notify(12  , notification);
}
```

Still i am getting continuous sound.
how to solve it?

Comment: When do you trigger creation of notification? Is it repeatly?

Comment: Share some more code , how are you building your notification ?

Comment: i updated the whole code

Comment: What is the solution?